# Qt Desktop listening to ports using Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: qt, node.js, socket.io

I built a desktop application using Qt.  Currently, the application pulls data at regular intervals from XML files on a remote web server to populate various widgets in the application.

Instead of pulling the data, I would rather implement a "push" environment where the Qt application establishes a persistent connection to a port on the remote web server and listens for updates or "broadcasts" from node.js.

I have already built something similar with a web-based application using node.js and socket.io, so I'm not new to this, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this in Qt.  I can make a connection to port 4000 using QTcpSocket and I can start the HTTP server with node.js, but I can't seem to pick up any messages that are broadcast.

The one piece that's missing here is socket.io, but I don't know how to use it or establish the required connection inside Qt -- so I'm at a loss.

**Connect and Listen on port 4000 inside Qt Application**

```
void MainWindow::connectTcp() {

client = new QTcpSocket(this);
QHostAddress hostadd("myIPaddress");
connect(client,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(isConnected()));
    connect(client,SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this,SLOT(connectionError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readTcpData()));
client->connectToHost(hostadd,3000);

}
```

**Create server in node.js and send updates**

```
var http = require('http'); 
var url = require('url');
var msg = '';

var port = 4000;
/* path to socket.io */
var path = '/path/to/node_modules/socket.io';

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

        req.on('data', function (d) {
            data += d;
        });
        req.on('end',function(){
            msg = data;
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.write(msg);
    res.end();
    console.log('SEND DATA: ',msg);
        });

}).listen(port);
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated -- is what I'm trying to do even possible?

**EDIT -- UPDATE**

After failing to incorporate Socket.io and WebSocket using C++, I tried to do it with QWebView and it worked.  I'm sharing the details of what I did below in case anyone else needs help.

**mainwindow.cpp**

This is just a generic Qt Gui Application whose only purpose is to create a QWebView instance that loads an HTML file.  The HTML file that is being loaded (in the background) contains the javascript code that establishes the socket connection.

I created a separate Qt class to interface with the javascript in index.html to act on the responses from the server. [More Info](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit-bridge.html)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Set default proxy (this may not always be necessary)
    QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);

    h = new Hello(this);

    view = new QWebView(this);
    view->load(QUrl("http://www.mydomain.com/startconnection.html"));

    // I don't want the webview to show, it should run in the background
    view->hide(); 

    frame = view->page()->mainFrame();
    connect(view,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));

}

void MainWindow::loadFinished(bool loaded) {

    qDebug() << "Webpage Loaded? " << loaded;

}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**http://www.mydomain.com/startconnection.html**

This is the page that gets loaded into Qt.  It simply establishes the Socket.io connection to mydomain.com which is listening for connections on port 4000

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

var socket;

window.onload = onLoad;

function onLoad() {

    socket = io.connect('http://www.mydomain.com:4000');

    socket.on('connect', function(){
        alert("Connected To Socket");
    });

    socket.on('message',function(data) {
        alert("Here Comes A Message From The Server");
    });

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/socket/server.js**

This is the node script that starts the HTTP service listening for connections on port 4000.  I started the service with "forever" and output all console.info messages to a log file like this: forever -al /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/connection.log start /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.dom/socket/server.js.

```
var http = require('http'); 
var url = require('url');
var qs = require('querystring');
var child_process = require('child_process');
var theSockets = {};

/* listening port */
var port = 4000;
/* path to socket.io on server */
var path = '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/server/node_modules/socket.io';

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

         var data = '';
         var msg = '';

        req.on('data', function (d) {
                data += d;
        });

        req.on('end',function(){
            msg = data;
            io.sockets.emit('message',msg);
            res.end();
        });

        }

        res.end();

}).listen(port);

var io = require(path).listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var d = new Date();
    console.log('JOINED SOCKET '+d.toLocaleString()+' SOCKET ID '+socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect',function() {

    var d = new Date();
    console.log('EXITED SOCKET '+d.toLocaleString()+' SOCKET ID '+socket.id);

    });

});
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Class socket.io server callback function for Qt on GITHUB : https://github.com/ChadyG/QtSocketIOServer

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, yes, but you'll have to understand Socket.IO deals with WebSocket sockets, not raw TCP. Your client should do a WebSocket handshake with the server, etc. What's currently happening is that you create a "HTTP" connection on the client side, send nothing and wait for something to happen. (Nothing will happen.)

Of course you can also devise a protocol to run on top of raw TCP, for instance sending newline/null separated (or netstring encapsulated) blobs of JSON.

Comment: Thanks.  I googled around and found this [Github Link](https://github.com/ebshimizu/socket.io-clientpp) with a version of Socket.io written for C++.  Requires Boost and other dependencies.  I'll give it a shot and respond if it works out.

Comment: No luck. I installed Boost libraries for C++ using instructions from the Boost.org website and [here](http://cpp-qt-mac-win.blogspot.com/2011/10/qt-boost-for-beginners-step-by-step.html) and then I installed [rapidjson](http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/wiki/UserGuide).  I installed Socket.io and WebSockets.  I got a bunch of errors -- leading me to believe this solution is only for Microsoft Visual C++, not for Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [QWebSockets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-index.html), which implements websockets using Qt. I also have build both client and server socket.io classes, which will be open sourced soon.

EDIT: 
Find it [here](https://github.com/Xsmael/Qt-Websocket)

Comment: IT woudl nice to see your implementation, grat job!